# addEventListener Function wont Execute

Tags: javascript

can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('wow')
});
```

I dont get any error, but nothing is logged onclick.

Comment: Works fine for me in a snippet-- are you sure that you're clicking on the body itself?  It may only be as tall as the content it contains...

Comment: There are several things that could cause this issue. Absent html or other context, we can only assume which one is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no content in the body, so it has a height of `0px`. You can set its height:

```js
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('wow')
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or attach the `click` event listener to the `document` instead:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('wow')
});
```